Do quantified statements without domains mean anything? What is one to do when it seems impossible for there to be any domain?
I used to find quantified statements without domains perfectly sensible, but now I can hardly grasp them. Such statements are in introductory texts, proof assistants, and many other places. When a statement concerns numbers, it almost always has a domain, and there is no ambiguity. In many other statements, however, there is less clarity.
How am I to claim that, say, apples exist in FOL? ∃x[A(x)], where A(x) is "x is an apple."? What does that mean? Consider the following example: ∃x∈N(x = 1). At least one element of the set of natural numbers is 1. Clear as day, indubitably true, and totally straightforward. What about the previous statement? There is no domain. What does the statement even claim? What is its truth contingent on?
In the absence of a domain, I took some time to think about x. It is a variable, a symbol representing an entirely indeterminate object that can only be restricted and consequently made meaningful through other statements, which claim that x has some property, that x is equal to something and so on. A variable represents something. That's it. Does the statement about apples then mean that something is an apple? That may be obvious and entirely sensible, but then I do not understand why any ambiguity is associated with such statements and how that statement could be interpreted.

"I do not understand why any ambiguity is associated with such statements and how that statement could be interpreted." $\quad$ As a matter of fact, the agreed interpretation  helps determine the statements' truth values.


how that statement [a quantified one] could be interpreted?

With an interpretation that assigns meaning to the symbols of a language.
The logical symbols like the connectives, are interpreted through truth-tables, and thus their meaning is topic independent, i.e. it does not depend on the specific domain of discourse to which the formula applies.
The universal quantifier expresses generality, i.e. allows us to assert that a statement holds in all instances.
But instances of what?
This is the role of the domain of the interpretation: if we interpret the formula $\forall x A(x)$ in the domain $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers and we interpret the symbol $A$ as expressing the property "is odd", then the formula will be interpreted as "every (natural) number is odd".
If we move to a different intepretation with domain the real world and the symbol $A$ expresses the property "is an apple", the formula will be interpreted as "every thing is an apple".
There are formulas, like e.g. $\forall x (x=x)$ and $\forall x P(x) \lor \lnot \forall x P(x)$, whose truth value is the same for every interpretation: they are called (logically) valid.

Usually when their are quantifiers without the domain stated, the sentences are potential axioms that a structure may satisfy.
Suppose we have the sentences:

$\forall x\forall y\forall z, (x\ast y) \ast z = x\ast (y \ast z$,
$\forall x, x\ast e = e\ast x = x$.
$\forall x, x\ast x^{-1} = x^{-1}\ast x = e$.

Then any structure $\mathfrak{A} = (G, \ast, e, ^{-1}) $ with a binary operation $\ast$ on a set $G$, a constant $e\in G$ and a unary operation $^{-1}$ that satisfies the sentences 1,2 and 3 above is known as a group.
Of course, we could write $\forall x\in G$, but not all groups need to be denoted by $G$.
